# Is there a way to play iTunes U files at 2x speed?

Tags: itunes, audio, speed, playback

I'd like to keep my iTunes U audio files organized in the iTunes U category in iTunes; however, I can't seem to do that AND find a way to open the option to play at variable speeds for these audio files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of iTunes replacements. Such as [Miro4](http://www.getmiro.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. even if I don't get the dependency between order and playback speed.

`mplayer -speed 2 some_lecture`